# What dose these units means in zabbix?

Tags: monitoring, io, zabbix, write, zabbix-agent

When i try to set some items for my disk read and write, I found it by `vfs.dev.read` and `vfs.dev.write`for zabbix-agent. This item contain a parameter named `type` which some of them are unknown for me.

What's the meaning of the below units?

1. operations
2. sps
3. ops
4. bps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is mentioned in the [documentation](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.0/manual/config/items/itemtypes/zabbix_agent)

> sectors, operations, bytes, sps, ops, bps (must be specified, since defaults differ under various OSes). 
>   sps, ops, bps stand for: sectors, operations, bytes per second, respectively

Comment: Thank you. I read the 1.8 manual, But in 2.0 describe them more. Any way, May i ask to describe them more by operations?

Comment: @shgnInc I decline. I will leave that as an excercise for you to improve your searching skills.

Comment: @lain Thank you for giving me that opportunity for improving my skills, but Please just tell what dose `operations` means as a unit in that key?